# why should someone study mRNAs instead of miRNAs as a biomarker

Tags: human-biology, gene-expression

why should someone study mRNAs instead of miRNAs as a biomarker from liquid cell-free biopsy like from exosomes? Is it wrong to do it? Does it offer you something different? Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you think? Have you looked anywhere for pros and cons? Can you add that information to your question/rationale?